# Auxiliary parameters for two uncertain parameters Robust Optimization

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, modeling, robust-optimization

I have the following constraint for robust counterpart formulation, where two uncertain parameters appear at the same time;

$\sum{QG_{ij}}$*${\theta}$+$\sum_{}\sum{QD_{ij}}*p $ * ${\theta}$

where;
${QG}$ and ${QD}$ are decision variables.

${p}$ and ${\theta}$ are uncertain parameters.

In order to overcome the issue of the two parameters in the second term, I defined an auxiliary parameter, let it be;

${\beta}$= ${p}$ * ${\theta}$

Then the constraint becomes;

$\sum{QG_{ij}}$*${\theta}$+$\sum_{}\sum{QD_{ij}}$ * ${\beta}$

I am wondering if this simplification is valid or not.

Comment: I meant  ${p}$ * ${\theta}$ in both expressions, it was a typo, thank you, I fixed it.